# Installing GeoIP on CentOS

Tags: centos, centos6, geoip

On CentOS 6 I cannot install GeoIP even though many websites describe installing GeoIP with the following commands:

```
yum install GeoIP GeoIP-devel GeoIP-data
```

I get `No package GeoIP available.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like you need to add an additional repository. In CentOS5 the Geoip stuff was located in Centos Extras. Check out this link: 
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

If the package is not in Extras try out the EPEL repo (howto is in the link above), they have the packages:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/letter_g.group.html

Comment: It was in EPEL. Extras was already enabled by default.

Comment: how do i install on ubuntu

Comment: On Ubuntu : sudo apt-get install libgeoip-dev

Comment: To add EPEL repo you can do `yum install epel-release`

Comment: seems like your last link is not working any longer

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the accepted answer above by @zaub3r3r - (Sorry I don't have enough rep to comment here)

GeoIP is in EPEL. You might have it but it may not be enabled - if this is the case then try:

```
yum -y --enablerepo=epel install geoip
```

This had me stumped for ages today until I realised what was going on.